# Spring JMS DefaultMessageListener and Transactions

Tags: spring-jms

My DefaultMessageListernerFactory bean looks like

```
@Bean
  public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
      DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
   factory.setSessionTransacted(false);
   factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    factory.setErrorHandler(new DefaultJMSErrorHandler());
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    return factory;
  }
```

Using @JmsListener and when my application throws an exception -- I expected my messsage to NOT be requed back but I notice that it is. I thought sessionTransaction(false) should not exhibit this behavior.

I noticed my transaction logs saying this

```
2019-09-20 14:22:42.609 DEBUG 17252 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Initiating transaction rollback on application exception
```

During debug, I noticed that the DefaultMessageListner has sessionTransacted to be true. It also creates a JMS session with a mode(0) -- SESSION_TRANSACTED

I am obviously missing something.

Can someone tell me what I am missing here ?

FYI -- I am using IBM MQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`factory.setSessionTransacted(false);`

You need to do that AFTER `configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);`, which has this code...

```java
        if (this.transactionManager != null) {
            factory.setTransactionManager(this.transactionManager);
        }
        else {
            factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
        }
```